# Can I "daisy-chain" LED strip lights to my bathroom exhaust fan and have them work on the same light switch?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, led

I just finished installing a new exhaust fan in my bathroom. I have access to the ceiling before I patch up the old hole where the old fan used to be. A lot of people tend to connect a recessed light to the exhaust fan but I wanted to know if I could "daisy-chain" an LED strip light so that it could illuminate the side of the walls as you can see in this photo:

Here are the LED lights that I bought:

[image]

Comment: The simple answer is yes, this is possible, but you don't provide nearly enough detail for your situation. First, are you even in the US? Second, what kind of LED strips will you be using? Many daisy-chained off each other, meaning one end of the stip is powered and the other is either terminated or bridged to another strip. Third, your description of "daisy-chaining" seems inaccurate. You would actually be powering the LED strips in parallel. Essentially, we need more information about what you want to do and what you're willing to do to make it happen.

Comment: Yes. my exhaust fan even has a standard US plug i used a 3:1 adapter with to do the same...

Comment: Sorry, I normally add "USA" at the end of my title when I ask questions. I didn't know if it did any good and the one time I didn't type someone wants clarification. :) When I say daisy chain, I mean split the Romex in half, one half to continue powering the exhaust and the other one to power the lights. I am not certain what lights I want to get but the room 8x6 so that's about 28ft. I haven't decided on what to get but whatever works for a bathroom and allows me to run one continuous LED strip. The photo I provided should make that clear to you, Hari.

Comment: So, you want the LED strip to power up when the fan turns on? You would add the LED driver to the circuit of the fan. Several ways to do this, hardwire or cord? I would do this "split" before it gets to the fan, otherwise you may get a flicker or something related to the fan running. I had CFLs do this years ago, every time the fan came on, the lights in the bathroom do too, causing a flicker. It had to do with how the previous person wired the sockets.

Comment: How do I connect these so they don't flicker? I am providing a photo of the LED lights that I bought. I am going to run the Romex from the fan and then put an outlet and use a USB adapter to keep these plugged in so they turn on when the fan turns on. I am changing the design a bit. I bought four 19" LED strip lights. I am putting two of them on each of the two cabinets I have. One will go at the top of the cabinet to illuminate upward and the second one will go at the bottom of the cabinet to light the cubby hole. So I am going to run two Romex wires in two different directions to do this.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer  or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to complete my task by installing a junction box I attached to the joists inside the ceiling above the drywall. It is accessible if I remove the exhaust fan from the ceiling. From this junction box I ran a Romex wire to the medicine cabinet and a similar sized cabinet on the opposite wall that was hung above the toilet to store toiletries, etc. I then cut out an a rectangle shaped hole to install an outlet inside each of the cabinets. These outlets only had power when the exhaust fan was turned on at the wall switch. I then plugged in an LED light strip kit I purchased online and strategically ran the strip lights along the upper side of the cubbyholes that each cabinet had. I also ran a strip of LED lights along the tops of the cabinets which, when turned on illuminated the wall and ceiling above each cabinet. The cubbyholes were also illuminated. This worked perfectly. No flickering or issues. Wish I could provide a photo of how it turned out but I no longer live in this house. These made a great nightlight effect when you just wanted enough light in the bathroom to see where you're going. Also created a nice relaxing ambiance when taking a long hot bath.

Comment: `It is accessible if I remove the exhaust fan from the ceiling.` I'm 99.99% sure the NEC wouldn't call this accessible! If you have to use a screwdriver to remove a cover plate, that's acceptable. If you have to remove one box from _inside_ the wall to get access to another box _inside_ the wall, that's not!

Comment: `I no longer live in this house` I hope that you disclosed this wiring hack to your landlord or purchasers when you moved out.

Answer (score 2):

Since your LED strips are powered by a 5V DC the correct answer is:

> **No, you can't directly add DC equipment to an AC circuit.**

However, you can add a 110 V AC outlet to the switchable part of the circuit that the fan is on and plug in what ever adapter you were planning on running your LEDs off of from that.

Assuming you want these LEDs on the ceiling near the center of the room, you probably want to use a ceiling box (for lights) instead  of a standard switch box so that any future owner, or change in taste will allow you easily to convert to another fixture.
[image: Picture of ceiling boxes]
along with a cover like this:
[image]
They also sell these in decora or single outlet style:
[image]

Alternately, (and what I'd probably do) in place of a ceiling box, you could install a recessed light fixture, then use a socket to outlet adapter and plug your 5V DC transformer into that:

[image: socket adapter]

I see that in your comments you are worried about flickering. This shouldn't be a problem, unless the circuit is overloaded (if so you need to run a new line from your breaker box), or had a ton of compact florescent bulbs on it (they dirty the power by only pulling during the maximum voltage differential).

Comment: The circuit itself for the bathroom only has three LED Edison bulbs that don't even equal 35W total. Then there is the power of the fan itself. I think I should be good to go. I will look for a 110V AC outlet to connect to the Romex in the ceiling to power the LED lights. Thank you!